# DASL Filter in Outlook to select Mails by their EntryID

Tags: outlook, mapi, mailitem

I'm trying to apply a DASL Filter [customized View] on a search Folder with this SQL query:

> ```
> "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFF0102" = '000000001CF4984B1BD06249A3C1E9DBBE2C6F65E4C82200'
> ```

I'd like to select only mails by their entryIDs which I found in a previous search. The searchfolder contains definitely the mail  with that entryID.

Applying sth like this on same folder

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003" = '102'
```

works.

Is it not possible to do this? Or is my SQL query not correct?

Comment: Can you share a little more of your code?

Comment: actually, question is only about sql query in a customized view.

Comment: I've found [this forum thread](http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/exchange-apps/688/Message-from-EntryID), suggesting that you should Base64-encode the entry ID, instead of passing the hex string.

Comment: thanks for this hint - I'm still trying to understand this.

Comment: I used [link](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Encode/Default.aspx) to encode my EntryID to Base64 but the mail is still no found

Comment: You cannot encode the Hex string as Base64, that's what I was saying. You must get the actual bytes and encode *them* as Base64, at least that's what the forum thread is implying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the `EntryID`, simply call `Namespace.GetItemfromID`.
There is no reason to search.

**UPDATE:** On a more general note, OOM would not let you search on a binary (`PT_BINARY`) property. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), its versions of [RDOItems](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`Find/Restrict` will let you specify a binary property using the syntax above. To retrieve an [RDOFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm) object, create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object and call `RDOSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject` passing an instance of the `MAPIFolder` object from OOM - you will get back an `RDOFolder` object.

Comment: But that's not what I want - I'd like to apply this via customized view, because I'd like to have a collection of items by entryID in that searchfolder listed.

Comment: What is the criteria used to create the list of matching messages? You can set a custom property on all matching messages, then create a search folder that looks for the messages with that property.

Comment: Yes, this is nice - I was thinking to give it up. Because it seems not to be possible to use the entryid property with that.
But with your hint I achieved what I wanted . Thanks a lot Dmitry :-)

Comment: @lepos  I am looking to achieve something similar, would you mind sharing your code to help others including myself please?